# Creating Undirected Graph With Correct Edges

Tags: c++, graph, nodes, dijkstra

Hello I'm creating 100 graphs for testing in dijkstra's algorithm. I have a check to make sure that two random generated node numbers for a connection are not the same. However I am not understanding how to check if a pair already exists so that more than one edge occurs between two nodes. How do I prevent two edges between two nodes from occurring?

```
void mapDataGenerator(int start, int end, int iterations,
                        int *pathCount, int *weightCount, int *timeCount)
{
int nodeCount = rand() % 8128 + 64;
edgeListTemplate edgeList(nodeCount);
//cout << "The node count is: " << nodeCount;
int n = 0;
list<vertex_v> path;
vector<weight_w> min_distance;
vector<vertex_v> previous;


while (n != nodeCount)
{

    int nodeNumb = (rand() % nodeCount); // Generates a possible node 1 
    int nodeDest = (rand() % nodeCount); // Generates a possible node 2

    //cout << "The node connection 1 is: " << nodeNumb << endl;
    //cout << "The node connection 2 is: " << nodeDest << endl;
    int node_weight = rand() % 5 + 1; // Generate random weight of node

    //cout << "The node weight is: " << node_weight << endl;

    // Create adjacency list
    if (nodeNumb != nodeDest) // if the random nodes generated are not same
    {
        edgeList[nodeNumb].push_back(node(nodeDest, node_weight));
        // For undirected graph create opposite connection back 
        edgeList[nodeDest].push_back(node(nodeNumb, node_weight));
        ++n;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would upvote this question, but obviously you have to check if the edge exists...

Comment: That is my question, how would I check if the edge exists?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a map/set data structure to keep track of already present edges. Precisely map of pair will be do the job.

**Code**

```
// map declaration
map<pair<int, int>, bool> M;

if (nodeNumb != nodeDest && !M.count(make_pair(nodeNumb, nodeDest))) // if the random nodes generated are not same
{
     // Marking the pair of edges
     M[make_pair(nodeNumb, nodeDest)] = true;
     edgeList[nodeNumb].push_back(node(nodeDest, node_weight));
     // For undirected graph create opposite connection back 
     edgeList[nodeDest].push_back(node(nodeNumb, node_weight));
     ++n;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you that is a great solution.

Comment: oh, you 2 are boosting.

Comment: Just because I cannot add comment to question , I added as an answer.